# Misere NIM game

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having difficulty trying to attempt this question. Any help would much be appreciated.
Thank you.

In (9,2,31)−Misère NIM, the game begins with a pile of N stones. On their turn, a player can take 1, 2, or 3 stones. The player that takes the last stone loses the game.

(a) Do a complete analysis of Misère NIM as the game is defined above. Determine which player has a winning strategy for any value of N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For only $7$ stones, you can do it by hand.  Define the positions as $P$(revious) and $N$(ext) depending on whether the previous player wins or the next player wins.  A position is $N$ exactly when there is a move to a $P$ position.  It is $P$ if there is no move to an $N$ position.    Who wins a game with 1 stone?  With 2 stones?  With 3?  Once you get to $7$ stones maybe you can see a pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did that, I got the winning positions to be 2,3,4 and loosing positions to be 1, 5,6,7. I'm I on the right track? And how do I figure out which player has the winning strategy? I see that, regardless of who starts, if played well any can end up winning.

Comment: $1$ is $P$ and $2,3,4$ are $N$ as you say, because they can move to $1$.  Then $5$ is $P$ because you have to move to $N$, but $6$ and $7$ can move to $5$ and win.  So the first player wins $2,3,4,6,7$ and the second player wins $1,5$ if play is rational.

Comment: Thanks got it. But what does it mean exactly by which player has a winning strategy?

Comment: When I say the first player has a winning strategy it means he can win regardless of what the second player does.  Which one has a winning strategy depends on the starting number.  For $7$, the first player has a winning strategy, which is to take two.  You want to move to an $N$ position.  Now from $5$, the second player will take some number and the first can move to $1$ and win.  If you start with more stones, he just works down the chain of $N$ numbers.  This should show you how to handle b and c.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand what it means by winning strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Break into cases as to whether the number of stones is equal to $1$ or not mod $k+1$. Try to prove that if the number of starting stones is equal to $1$ mod $k+1$ then the first player is guaranteed to lose because the second player can keep the number of stones equal to $1$ mod $k+1$ regardless of the first player's move, until finally the number of stones for the first player to choose from is equal to $1$. Similarly prove that if the number of stones is not equal to $1$ mod $k+1$, then the first player can win by setting the number of stones equal to $1$ mod $k+1$ and then steal the winning strategy of the second player.

Comment: what would k represent?

Comment: $k$ is your $k$ in part (c), where the number of stones taken can be any of $1,2, \ldots, k$.

Comment: Oh I got it, thanks. Let me try to do it now.

Comment: Thanks got it. But what does it mean exactly by which player has a winning strategy?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an inspiration for the solution to a problem it is often helpful to try out small cases especially with what we have here.

In the list below $W$ denotes a win for the first player if he plays with the best strategy, and $L$ denotes a loss for the first player if his opponent plays with his best strategy. We will let $n$ denote the number of stones in our starting configuration.

*$n$ is on the left column

$1:L$

$2:W$

$3:W$

$4:W$

$5:L$

$6:W$

$7:W$

$8:W$

$9:L$

$10:W$

When $n=1$ the first player loses no matter what

When $n=2$ the first player can leave the second player with $1$ stone by taking away $1$ stone thereby forcing his opponents loss. Similar logic applies for $n=3,4$

When $n=5$ your opponent can get $2,3,4$ rocks all of which will result in him winning as we have shown previously.

If we recursively apply this logic we cant work out which player has a different strategy for any given $n$.

Generally if $n\equiv1\,(mod\,4)$ the second player has a winning strategy, and in every other case the first player has the winning strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Nim with n-stones and removing 1, 2, or 3-stones at each turn. Person removing last stone looses.

Working the problem backwards, it is your turn:

If there is 1-stone left you lose.
If there are 2-stones left take 1.
If there are 3-stones left take 2.
If there are 4-stones left take 3.
If there are 5-stones left take 1, you probably lose.
If there are 6-stones left take 1.
If there are 7-stones left take 2.
If there are 8-stones left take 3.
If there are 9-stones left take 1, you might lose.
If there are 10-stones left take 1.
If there are 11-stones left take 2.
If there are 12-stones left take 3.
If there are 13-stones left take 1, you might lose.

Therefore, leave your opponent $1+x(s+1)$ where $s =$ the maximum number of stones you can take per move.

With n-stones for the starting player, there is a 25% probability he/she will lose when both players use this strategy.