# A game with multiple stones on a board (Combinatorial Game)

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

We have a game here. The game is played on a $10x10$ board. Here are the rules:

- Stones are placed on these squares as in the picture below.
- We have two players with alternating moves.
- As a legal move, we can move any stone by leftward, downward, and
  downward diagonal to any square. (Moves can be of any length greater than or equal to 1).
  *Each stone has a role similar to that of a chess queen*
- In any square, there can be any number of stones.
- At each turn, only one stone is allowed to move.
- Once all the stones are placed in the square located at the bottom left corner of the table, the game finishes.
- The one who plays the last legal move **loses** the game (*misère convention*).

[image: Initial]

**Now we are asked to show the position above is a Normal position. And we are asked to find the all possible winning moves.**
Here is my attempt:
[image: Attempt]

**Edit:** This initial attempt was **WRONG** as this is not a Normal game but a Misére one. So, I fixed this:
[image]

I know that I cannot continue forever by labeling as this.The game is more complex than it looks. I am open to any suggestions. Well, perhaps using Sprague-Grundy function can be useful but I don't know how to make use of it. Thanks in advance.

**Normal Position (N-position):** They are the positions which are winning for the Next player to move.
**Previous Position (P-position):** Positions that are winning for the Previous player (the player who just moved):

So, the player aiming to win tries to make a move that puts the next player in a P-position.

Comment: What do you mean by a *Normal* position?  Does this mean a *losing* position?  Also, my understanding is that on each turn, the player is required to move exactly one stone, and move it either down, left, or diagonally down-left, correct?  This means that you can't make a *chess-knight* move of down 2, and to the left 1, correct?  It also means that you can move the stone (for example) all the way downward to the bottom row, correct?

Comment: Maybe we can calculate the nim values of the games with only one rock?

Comment: @user2661923 Sorry for the inconvenience, I edited to post. Normal position is the position you are trying to be have in your turn. P-position is the position you try to put your opponent by making a move at your turn. And, yes, moves can be any length greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: @Théophile Yes, indeed. Each stone has a similar role to that of a chess queen.

Comment: @TonyK Sorry for the inconvenience. I added the details. Moves can be of any length (>0).

Comment: @TonyK I think it is crystal clear with the explanations.

Comment: Hint: The 1st thing to do is notice whether a stone requires 1 move or 2 moves to get to the lower left hand corner.  Noting that the game is played on a *perfect square* rather than a rectangle, any square that is either on the main diagonal, on the bottom row, or on the left column is 1 move away.  All other squares are two moves away.

Comment: If each square (in a single-stone game) does indeed correspond to a nimber, then we really should be recursively filling in the nimbers in each square, not just whether they are winning/losing (nonzero/zero nimber).

Comment: OP, are you sure you meant to say the player who moves last **loses**? The "normal convention" where the last mover *wins* is much more well studied, see [this other MSE question about finding the P-values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4063795/showing-that-losing-positions-in-wythoffs-game-are-generated-by-lfloor-n-phi) (though this is not enough to solve multiple counter positions).

Comment: Oh yeah I guess that is wythofs game lol.

Comment: Oh, but we are adding multiple wythof games, so the grundy numbers do help.

Comment: Also, if it is truly the case that the last mover loses, your partial table would be incorrect; the lower left square should be N (no moves = win), while the squares adjacent to the lower left should be P (their only option is N). So, do you think you erred in the problem statement, or the calculation?

Comment: I found this, which is useless but interesting https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737078/misere-nim-game

Comment: The misère version of Wythoff's game (under the name "Wyt Queens") is briefly discussed on pp. 407ff in Vol. 1 of "Winning Ways."  It says, "You'll find by trial that the misère version has a genus table which appears to be entirely tame."  It says that every queen outside the leading $3\times3$ square which can "see" a $0$ or a $1$ in this square can also see the other, "and using this, we can prove that every entry outside this square is both firm and tame."  Even if I ever understood this (dubious), I don't now.  Maybe you can figure it out.

Comment: I think it's kind of funny that when you remove the misere condition the problem has a solution that is particularly quick

Comment: EDIT: Initial attempt was completely WRONG as the terminal position should have been labeled as 'N'. So, I fixed that. Sorry for that. @MikeEarnest

Comment: @Jorge It turns out your answer was correct, though it was only obvious after seeing saulspatz's comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your game is known as the misere variatnnt Wythoff's game. In general, the Sprague-Grundy theorem does not hold for misere games, meaning you cannot always replace misere games in a sum by equivalent nim heaps. However, this is true for a subclass of games called *tame* games. According to *Winning Ways, vol 2*, page $427$, the positions of Wythoff's game are indeed tame.

There is no simple rule to determine the normal nim value of a Wythoff's game position, but we can calculate them recursively. Below are the results according to *Winning Ways*. Here, $n$ is an abbreviation for the firm genus $n^n$ (see *Winning Ways* vol 2 p. 413 and on for the definitions of these terms and the theory behind them). Using this, we solve this [using Jorge's reasoning](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4086933/177399) <strike>in a deleted answer</strike>. Namely, the position is equivalent to the misere-nim position

$$
9\oplus5\oplus5\oplus5\oplus8\oplus4\oplus4\oplus11\oplus11\oplus16=9\oplus5\oplus8\oplus16=20
$$
This is nonzero, so we are looking at an $N$-position. Since all summands are firm, the winning move is to one where the nim sum of the normal-play Grundy values is zero. Since there are no options with a summand of $16$, the winning move must be to replace $16$ with $4$, so the unique winning move is to move the upper right counter diagonally one space.

$$\text{Genera for Wythoff's game}\\\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 8 & 7 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\ \hline
8 & 6 & 7 & 10 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 15 \\ \hline
7 & 8 & 6 & 9 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 14 \\ \hline
6 & 7 & 8 & 1 & 9 & 10 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 13 \\ \hline
5 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 10 & 1 & 2 & 7 \\ \hline
4 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 7 & 6 & 9 & 0 & 1 & 8 \\ \hline
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 9 & 10 & 12 \\ \hline
2 & 0^1 & 1^0 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 6 & 7 & 11 \\ \hline
1^0 & 2 & 0^1 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 10 \\ \hline
0^1 & 1^0 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: So I guess knowing genus theory all we had to do was calculate the genus table (if such a thing exists) and verify it is tame for our $10\times 10$ grid right? I am reading this wikipedia page but it doesn't seem to make sense. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_theory#Tame

Comment: Oh ok, it says the genus can be used to predict the outcome of:

    The sum of any nimbers and any tame games

Comment: So genus theory can also be used to solve the misere nim?

Comment: @Jorge Yes. Misere nim is easy: just play normal nim, unless the normal winning move is to leave an even number of heaps each with one stone each, in which case the misere winning move is to instead leave an odd number of one-heaps. For a modern streamlined introduction to misere game theory, one of the best sources is _Combinatorial Game Theory_ by Spiegel, chapter 5.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I'll just leave here as code to calculate the grundy values, which are an intermediate step to get the genus. See Mike's solution to see why this is useful for the actual problem ( I initially didn't see it was misere)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int n = 10;
int S[n][n];

int main(){
        cout << "$\\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}" << endl;
  cout << "\\hline" << endl;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
      map<int,int> M;
      if( i == 0  && j == 0) continue;
      for(int d=1; ;d++){
        if( i - d < 0) break;
        M[ S[i-d][j]]++;
      }
      for(int d=1; ;d++){
        if( j - d < 0) break;
        M[ S[i][j-d]]++;
      }
      for(int d=1; ;d++){
        if( i - d < 0 || j-d < 0) break;
        M[ S[i-d][j-d]]++;
      }
      for(int x=0; ;x++){
        if( M[x] == 0){
          S[i][j] = x;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
      cout   << S[i][j] << " ";
      if( j == n-1) cout << "\\\\ \\hline" << endl;
      else cout << "& ";
    }
  }
  cout << "\\end{array}$" << endl;
}
```

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 8 & 7 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\ \hline
8 & 6 & 7 & 10 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 15 \\ \hline
7 & 8 & 6 & 9 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 14 \\ \hline
6 & 7 & 8 & 1 & 9 & 10 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 13 \\ \hline
5 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 10 & 1 & 2 & 7 \\ \hline
4 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 7 & 6 & 9 & 0 & 1 & 8 \\ \hline
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 9 & 10 & 12 \\ \hline
2 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 8 & 6 & 7 & 11 \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 10 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
\end{array}$

Comment: row 1 and column 1 should not have increasing sequences if the move can be any length.

Comment: Oh yeah I made a mistake

Comment: why not? Isn't it equivalent to a nim game with one pile of a given size?

Comment: @zwim Yes they should: consider nim with a single pile of stones.

Comment: I think you missed the last bullet point, that we are using the misère convention, which means we cannot just convert these guys to their nim values and play nim.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks! I'll try to fix it.

Comment: As a professional C++ programmer I beg of you,  please don't ever use *#include <bits/stdc++.h>*. Explicitly include only the headers you need.

Comment: You have no power here

Comment: Just kidding I'll try and get better with that sort of thing, it is very common in competitive programming though, which is really all that I have experience in. But I'm open to learning more.

Comment: Why would you suggest not using it? besides it relying on the GNU c++ library?

Comment: Number one your compile time is going to be huge. Secondly you're opening up the entire `std` namespace` so you're going to get name clashes one day. You obsficating what libraries you actually are using.

Comment: I used to get a lot of name clashes all the time but that hasn't happened to me for years.

Comment: @PaulEvans My compile time seems fine to me, why am I wrong (I'm sure I am).

Comment: Last point very important. Have to laboriously go through your code to see what standard libs you're actually using. Looks like you're going to carry on doing it anyway. But nobody will take your code seriously.

Comment: I didn't use anything, I just used a map which could have been avoided if I wasnt lazy, I also use the c++ output input I guess.

Comment: Guess it's like putting `y=3x+5` (only repeated thousands of times with different functions and different values) at the start of a proof that doesn't use any of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

I have converted my comment about **single stone strategy** to an image

[image]

I assume here an empty board with a single stone in one of the $99$ cells excepted $(0,0)$.

I coloured in red losing starting position and in green the winning positions, assuming of course both players play an optimal strategy.

- If the stone is in $(0,1)$ or $(1,0)$ [red cells with index $1$] then I'm forced to move to $(0,0)$ and lose the game.
- If the stone is in one of the green cells with index $2$ then since the move can be any length, I can move it to either $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ and my opponent loses.
- If the stone is in red $3$ then legal moves lead only to green cells and next turn my opponent is winning, or to $(0,0)$ I lose directly. Either way, this cell is losing.
- And I extend the board recursively like this.  Note that from red cells you can only reach green cells therefore this is a losing position. And green cells $n$ can always reach red cell $n-1$ on the next move, so it is a winning position.

This is how I understand the rules for just $1$ stone, and any length move in direction $\leftarrow,\downarrow,\swarrow$.

Comment: But then how can you use this for when there is more than $1$ stone?

Comment: Yeah, that's the next step, I haven't though about it yet :-)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375114/nimbers-for-mis%C3%A8re-games

Comment: @Jorge That sort of explains why this is not straightforward, but doesn't really get into what it takes to solve something like this. That's arguably covered over 4-5 sections of the text [Combinatorial Game Theory](https://www.ams.org/books/gsm/146/).